# IDE hangs at "Saving components to project" whenever I refresh from server

Tags: soap-api, metadata, ide

Something like 75% of the time I attempt to refresh from server on a project in the Force.com IDE it gets the data from the server but then hangs for 10 minutes or more on the "Saving components to project" dialog box. As this is a local operation I can't see any reason why it would be taking this long. I'm using the standalone IDE, but also had issues when using it as an eclipse plugin. OS X 10.8 (but also happened on 10.7) on a 4-month-old Macbook Pro.

[image: The evil dialog in question.]

Comment: I have a similar issue on my PC; not sure why it takes so long.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? How much internet upload/download speed do you get? Also, what version of the IDE are you using?

Comment: I've also experienced this however it doesn't seem to be limited to refreshing from the server. There are a few threads on the Force.com boards that suggest it may be eclipse causing the slow down.

Comment: Are you saving to a production or sandbox org? When you save code back to a production org it will run all the apex tests which makes the commit take a long time if you have a large number of tests.

Comment: @Anup I'm on a 60mbit symetrical link (e.g. 60/up & 60/down) behind a firewall but the ruleset doesn't block any outbound traffic. On v25 of the IDE.

Comment: @Born2BeMild developer editions mostly, and this is just trying to refresh, not even trying to save changes back to salesforce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the major reason it was so horribly slow: I have large managed packages installed and was right click > force.com >  refresh from server on the project and not the src folder. This attempted to re-download the whole referenced packages bundle on every refresh which seems to be much less reliable in saving to project.

To get much improved results I now right click > force.com > refresh from server on the src folder under the project instead, which has dramatically increased performance.

Comment: Fun fact: the IDE seems to write protect the referenced packages folder on OS X, which may well be the reason for my hanging. Silly IDE, I don't want the immutable flag set on any parts of my project!

Answer (score 2):

When I hang on the IDE I usually just *cancel and restart the operation* (I get hangs a lot).

Doesn't seem like there is anything wrong, but if your not getting any response, you just need to try it again, even for large sets of APEX meta-data components it shouldn't take more than a minute or two.

And you should see some progress.

Also, maybe check and make sure you have the latest version of the IDE (Summer '12 as of today)

Comment: Yep, I'm on the most current version. To make things more "fun" sometimes it becomes unresponsive when waiting and the cancel button doesn't work. I guess from the replies so far that it's just an issue everybody has learned to live with.

Comment: Yeah that's the IDE for you... **BrainEngine** had a web-based IDE, that was made with Silver-light or something, but I think they shut it down or made it private )8

Comment: Exactly, you basically just have to learn to live with this, at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not the answer you're looking for - but you might consider MavensMate as alternate to Eclipse on the Mac:

https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate

Comment: this is not an answer but a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have had refreshes take a long time if I a. have selected a large number of components/types of components in the project and/or b. am pulling from an org with one or more installed packages. I've taken to start the refresh and go do something else, so I'm not sure where it hangs or exactly how long it takes. If you can't change a or b, I haven't found anything that increases the speed of the IDE.