# Too many DML rows: 10001

Tags: trigger, batch, limits

I have a trigger which performs an insert operation.One record count is more than 10k.So,Its giving this exception.I have tried batch apex and future method.Its is not working.Any help will be appreciated!

trigger:

```
trigger trgInsertRecord on Custom_object__c(after insert,after update) 
{   
Set<Id> clientIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Custom_object__c c:Trigger.new) {
        clientIds.add(c.Client__c);

            if(trigger.Isinsert) {                          
                Database.executeBatch(new BatchableClass(clientIds)); 
             }      
        }
 }
```

batchable class:

```
global class BatchableClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    Set<Id> clientIds = new Set<Id>();

    global BatchableClass(Set<Id> clientIdSet) { 
        clientIds = clientIdSet; 
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {   
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id,Client__c from Custom_object__c where Client__c IN:clientIds ]);     
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Custom_object__c> scope) {
        if (scope.isEmpty())
            return;
        for(Custom_object__c c:scope) {
            clientIds.add(c.Client__c);      

        //some logic to get objlist       

            insert objlist; 
        }
    }
 }
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IDE hangs at "Saving components to project" whenever I refresh from server](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87/ide-hangs-at-saving-components-to-project-whenever-i-refresh-from-server)

Comment: I think without you explaining more or posting some code answerers are going to be doing a lot of guessing.

Comment: I have update my question.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 Main issues:

**1)**

```
trigger trgInsertRecord on Custom_object__c(after insert,after update) 
{   
  Set<Id> clientIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Custom_object__c c:Trigger.new) {
        clientIds.add(c.Client__c);

            if(trigger.Isinsert) {                          
                Database.executeBatch(new BatchableClass(clientIds)); 
             }      
        }
 }
```

You are executing the same batch for as many items are in your trigger.

```
trigger trgInsertRecord on Custom_object__c(after insert,after update) 
{
  if (Trigger.isInsert)
  {
    Set<Id> clientIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Custom_object__c c:Trigger.new)
    {
      clientIds.add(c.Client__c);    
    }
    if (!clientIds.isEmpty())
    Database.executeBatch(new BatchableClass(clientIds));
  }
}
```

You only want to execute the batch once.

**2)**

It's essentially the same problem again in your batch:

```
for(Custom_object__c c:scope) {
            clientIds.add(c.Client__c);  



    //some logic to get objlist       

        insert objlist; 
    }
```

You need to do your work in bulk.

```
List<Other_object__c> objs = new List<Other_Object__c>();
for(Custom_Object__c obj: scope)
{
  //some work here
  objs.add(someObj);
}
insert objs;
```

Comment: I tried putting dml statement outside for loop.But facing the same issue again.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that "objlist" is being updated inside a for loop.  The code does not show us what type variable "objlist" is, so we can't determine exactly what is happening, but an insert operation inside a for loop is rarely a good idea.

If "objlist" was a list of "Custom_object__c" objects, I think we'd get infinitely repeating trigger calls (until the governor limits kicked in).

Either remove "objlist" from the for loop or explain why it needs to be there.